# Thunderbolt display for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: thunderbolt

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a MacBook Pro with Thunderbolt.  I also have an iMac with Thunderbolt which I wish to use as a monitor via target display mode.  Is it possible to set this up? It seems as though Ubuntu is not recognizing the Thunderbolt cable as a display.

Thanks for any help.

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
           +-01.0-[04-9a]----00.0-[05-6a]--+-00.0-[06]----00.0  Intel Corporation Device 1513
           |                               +-03.0-[07]--
           |                               +-04.0-[08-38]--
           |                               +-05.0-[39-69]--
           |                               \-06.0-[6a]--
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
           +-1a.0  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
           +-1b.0  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
           +-1c.0-[01]--+-00.0  Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
           |            \-00.1  Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader
           +-1c.1-[02]----00.0  Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
           +-1c.2-[03]----00.0  LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller
           +-1d.0  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
           \-1f.3  Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
```

Comment: AMD, What kind of Intel chip does your Mac have? Perhaps the iGPU doesn't have the right driver. Also could you update your question with the output of `lspci -tv`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find out what kind of intel chip the macbook has while running Ubuntu.  How can I find this out?  Question has been updated with that output.

Comment: To get the CPU model include output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'name'| uniq`

Comment: Welcome. I didn't even know the third generation had Thunderbolt. I thought it came out in the sixth generation, Skylake, ie like my i7 6700HQ CPU.

Answer (score 1):

From this [spec sheet](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html#macspecs2):

- Thunderbolt is backwards-compatible with Mini DisplayPort-equipped displays as well as adapters that are compatible with Mini DisplayPort (DVI, VGA, dual-link DVI and HDMI). It also can support other peripherals that use the Thunderbolt standard, which provides a maximum theoretical 10 Gbps of bandwidth in both directions.

You have a Thunderbolt 1 port which only supports 10 Gbps and not the common Thunderbolt 3 port USB Type C rated at 40 Gbps that are common today. Also keep in mind Apple cables/converters can be different than PC ones so make sure the specs are correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I found this adapter which after reading the overview looks like it may do the trick.  However it is quite expensive and want to be sure before I buy it.  Do you think this will work?

https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter?afid=p231%7Ccamref%3A11l3p&cid=AOS-US-AFF-PHG

Comment: That's going the opposite direction from Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2. You have a Thunderbolt 1 and you want to go to HDMI or Display Port right?

Comment: I want to go from Thunderbolt 1 to Thunderbolt 3

Comment: It' impossible to go from Thunderbolt 1 to Thunderbolt 3. That's like asking to make a slow car go faster. The adapter in your link is like making a fast car go slower which is possible when you apply brakes.